# Page not saving state of Media Element in WinRt

Tags: c#, windows-runtime

I'm trying out a Widows Store app in C#, using the MediaElement control. What i'm doing is to playing video and any time user can pause that video and navigate to some other page. When it come back to video page, that video will resume from its last postion. But in my case, when user navigate back to video page, its loses all state's of video Player like playback time, position. Code snipest is given below. Pls check and help me.

```
    public MainPage()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
        this.NavigationCacheMode = Windows.UI.Xaml.Navigation.NavigationCacheMode.Enabled;
    }

    protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.NavigationMode == NavigationMode.Back)
        {

            if (VideoPlayer.CurrentState == MediaElementState.Paused)
            {
                VideoPlayer.Play();     // Video Player MediaElement
            }
        }
    }

    private void NavigateButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (VideoPlayer.CurrentState != MediaElementState.Paused)
        {
            VideoPlayer.Pause();
            this.Frame.Navigate(typeof(SecondPage));
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

When you navigate to a page - by default a new instance of the page is created. You can change NavigationCacheMode of the page to enabled to keep it in memory, but then you have to take ownership of the resource management of the page and all memory it might be using. Alternatively you might want to simply save the position in that video when you navigate away from the page and restore the position once you get back, which makes more sense since it could then also survive the application being restarted or terminated and resumed.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It's very helpful if you provide some code snipest. Please